# Camera casting weird shadow depending only on it's position

Tags: camera, light, shadows, scene

As the title already explains I have a shadow in my render without an actual object which casts that shadow. The shadow only shows depending on where my camera is positioned and even when I disable the used lights in my scene.
Picture 1 shows how the object should look with the used lighting.
Picutre 2 shows the exact same object but I rotated the camera around it.
Picture 3 shows how that shadow increases while I rotate further around the object.
Picture 4 shows that there clearly is no other object in the way of the light and that camera itself could not cast the shadow on my object.

[image: Object with correct lighting/shadows]

[image: Shadow Position 1]

[image: Shadow Position 2]

[image: Setup of camera and lights]

Comment: What does your material node setup look like?

Comment: Here you can see my material node setup: [link](https://imgur.com/a/vblNgDh)

Comment: So I went in there and played with some settings. It looks like the normal input is causing that problem because if I cut the connection the shadow vanishes!

Comment: Yeah, I caught that. It's in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should solve your problem: Unless there is some special reason you're using "object", "generated" is usually the best texture coordinate to use for procedural textures. Secondly, if you're using a B&W value as a normal map, it should be run through the height input of a bump node first. See below:

[image: Setup]

Comment: There is no real reason for that. I think I copied that from somwhere else because I'm a beginner and don't really know what I'm doing there. ^^
That definitely did the trick and that weird shadow is gone, so thanks for both the advices!

Comment: @Tignite One thing to look out for is connecting sockets (the inputs/outputs of the nodes) to sockets of the same colour.The colour represents the type of data it handles. In your example you were connecting a Grey (scalar) output to the Blue (vector) Normal input of the shader node. This was producing an invalid surface normal which - as Christopher rightly pointed out - was the principle cause of the "shadow". Stick with connecting 'same colour' and you'll avoid some (but not all) of this kind of problem.